# Dúvida função PHP - mb_strlen

Tags: php

Eu entendi como funciona o "mb_strlen", mas não entendi um exemplo:

```
<?php mb_strlen($string, '8bit'); ?>
```

O que seria esse "8-bit"???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `8bit` é uma das codificações internas de caracteres suportados em funções [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.mbstring.php) - `mb_[função]`.

Basicamente, essa codificação informa para as funções *Multibyte* como a *string* deverá ser convertida para que sejam executadas corretamente.

Por exemplo, se você executar o código abaixo vai obter as seguintes saídas:

```
<?php
    $string = 'ὼ'; // Caractere especial qualquer

    echo strlen($string);             // Saída: 3
    echo mb_strlen($string, '8bit');  // Saída: 3
    echo mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8'); // Saída: 1 - CORRETO!
```

Concluindo, a função `strlen()` funciona bem para caracteres da tabela [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) e a codificação `8bit` retorna incorretamente em relação ao `UTF-8`. O padrão `UTF-8` (**Unicode**) é o mais eficiente e [recomendado](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings.pt-br) pela **W3.org**.

Para saber qual é a codificação padrão setada no seu projeto, você pode executar:

```
<?php
    echo mb_internal_encoding(); // Aqui retornou: UTF-8
```

Ou para setar a codificação interna para o padrão `UTF-8`:

```
<?php
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

[Aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) você pode ver a lista das codificações suportadas.

Comment: "a função strlen() funciona bem para caracteres da tabela ASCII", não, o comportamento pode ser modificado se usar o [`overload`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.overload.php).

Comment: Sim, mas o recurso de *Overloading* internamente utiliza as funções *Multibyte String*: *"For example, mb_substr() is called instead of substr() if function overloading is enabled."* - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: Mas ainda utiliza a mesma função (você irá usar o mesmo `strlen()`). O comportamento da função é alterada, pior que isso, é alterada usando uma configuração disponível nativamente. Então, não há qualquer garantia de que usar `strlen()` será igual a usar `mb_strlen(..., '8bit')`, sem que saiba do overload. Nem sempre você tem controle sobre o ambiente. Se você estiver desenvolvendo um software em código aberto, por exemplo, você não possui qualquer certeza de como o ambiente está configurado, uma opção nativa do PHP modificará inteiramente o comportamento do `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

O segundo parâmetro é a codificação de caracteres que você está usando. Muito provavelmente você vai querer esse parâmetro setado como `UTF-8`,

Caso queira entender melhor a função sugiro dar uma olhada na referência clicando [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php)

Answer (score 1):

Resumo: O `strlen` não é confiável, mas o usar o `mb_string(..., '8bit') nem sempre é possível.

---

A pergunta é interessante, pelo fato do `8bit` não ser tipicamente comum, como dito nas outras respostas. Mas acho que a resposta do @Paul Imon, leva ao equivoco em vários casos. Não há nada de errado em `mb_strlen('ὼ', '8bit')` resultar `3`, você apenas está ignorando a codificação utilizada, essa resposta é correta para `8bit`.

Imagine que, por exemplo, você tenha as duas seguintes informações:

```
0xDF     0xBF
11011111 10111111
```

Isso são dois bytes qualquer, que podem (ou não) ter sido geradas de maneira uniforme. Se você estiver interessado em bytes, pouco importa sua codificação. O UTF-8 possui uma especie de "sinalização" para próximos bytes, por isso o primeiro byte indica quantos bytes existem, assim podemos trata-lo como um único caractere.

O UTF-8, por exemplo, sempre será um ASCII quando usado um único byte (0xxxxxxx), porém quando tem dois ele obrigatoriamente será (110xxxxx) e todos os bytes que não são o primeiro devem ser (10xxxxxx).

Este caractere NÃO EXISTE no UTF-8, experimente:

```
echo "\xDF\xBF"; //= ߿
```

Porém sua codificação indica que possui dois bytes, portanto executar:

```
echo mb_strlen("\xDF\xBF", 'UTF-8'); //= 1
```

Retornará `1`, mesmo que o caractere nem sequer exista. Mas, este caractere existe em UTF-16LE, esse conjunto de bytes representa `뿟` em UTF-16LE:

```
echo iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', "\xDF\xBF"); //= 뿟
```

Entretanto usar `8bit` irá resultar 2, afinal existem 2 bytes. Acredito que "errado" não seja a palavra que melhor descreva isso, porque todas as formas são corretas, dependendo de onde irá aplicar isso, claro.

---

O `8bit` irá tratar cada byte individualmente, independente da codificação, ele irá tratar cada byte como um byte, da forma mais simples possível, inclusive poderá usar valores fora do ASCII, como `0xFF`.

O `mb_strlen(..., '8bit')` deve ser usado para impedir problemas com a função de [`mbstring.func_overload`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.overload.php), que apenas agora se tornou *obsoleto*. Este problema não é aplicável se não possuir o *Multibyte String* instalado.

Então a resposta do @Paul Imon volta a ficar errada. Usando um recurso nativo da linguagem configurado no `php.ini` modifica o `strlen()` inteiramente:

```
mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

Teste:

```
echo strlen("\xDF\xBF");  //= 1
```

Veja, o comportamento do `strlen` já não é o mesmo do `mb_strlen(..., '8bit')`, se você usar o `mbstring.func_overload = 2`.

---

Resumo, se você quer lidar com bytes:

```
$texto = "\xDF\xBF";

if (extension_loaded('mbstring') && defined('MB_OVERLOAD_STRING') && ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & MB_OVERLOAD_STRING) {

 echo mb_strlen($texto, '8bit');

}else{

 echo strlen($texto);

}
```

Isso irá usar o `strlen` por padrão, mas se o *overload* estiver sendo usado, então usamos o `mb_strlen` para garantir que não iremos usar o `strlen` modificado. Lembre-se que nem todos possuem o mbstring instalado, portanto usar o `mb_string(..., '8bit')` como padrão não é sempre possível. Se você tem certeza de que o mbstring está instalado poderá usar somente o `mb_string(..., '8bit')`. ;)

Comment: "Não há nada de errado em `mb_strlen('ὼ', '8bit')` resultar 3" - Condordo! Porém, eu quis mostrar que em relação ao `UTF-8` está incorreto, já que a **W3** [recomenda](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings.pt-br) esse padrão para conteúdo web: *"Escolha UTF-8 para qualquer conteúdo..." - "Em Unicode existem três diferentes codificações de caracteres: UTF-8, UTF-16 e UTF-32. Destas três somente UTF-8 deve ser usada para conteúdo Web"*.

Comment: @PauloImon "recomenda". A palavra diz tudo. Se você não segue, não é "incorreto", apenas não recomendado. Ainda, no mesmo texto, UTF-8 deve ser escolhido SE usar unicode. A frase se aplica claramente ao unicode, e não a web como um todo. Tem uma incorreção na sua resposta, que é a afirmação que UTF-8 é mais eficiente. UTF-8 é muito ineficiente se comparado com ISO-8859, por exemplo, pq precisa sempre de processamento. Tabelas de 256 caracteres são sempre 1:1, eficientes em espaço e processamento. Uma simples busca reversa de posição em UTF-8 precisa varrer a string toda.

Comment: Minha resposta está aberta à edições, fique à vontade se quiser alterar algo.

Comment: Por mim existe uma outra questão, além do apontado pelo Bacco. Nem sempre estamos lidando com textos, nesses casos o UTF-8 é inaplicável. Se estiver, por exemplo, lendo uma imagem ou uma chave privada estará lidando apenas com "algum conjunto de bytes arbitrários", o PHP não tem formato especifico para bytes. O OP não especifica o contexto. O principal problema, ao meu ver, é que não há garantias de que o `strlen()` tenha sempre o mesmo comportamento do `8bit`, por isso usar o uso do `mb_strlen(.., '8bit')` se torna necessário.